# How to store big amount of data with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, ram

I have a 100+ MB of XML files, each contain different amount of nodes with info stored in attributes.
Like

```
<Node NodeID="100" Value="100500" Option1="Getting heavy"....>
<Node NodeID="101".....>
```

I need to access any of this elements at random time (so i cant separate the files and stream it bit by bit.)
I tried to convert the content of this XMLs into PHP arrays. Ive got arrays like 
`$FileName['Attribute']['NodeID'];`

But when i try to store even a 3MB+ files like that, PHP CLI process begins to use a huge (hundreds-thousands of MB) amount of RAM.
How can i efficiently store that much (100MB) of data, considering that i need to have a direct access to each separated element & Attribute?
Previous code that i used was about a huge amount of foreach() with simplexml object ( so instead of storing $FileName['Atrribute']['NodeID'] i opened the file and foreached it until the element with needed NodeID was found ,and then extracted its attribute. But the more one-time interactions i need, the more time is needed for all that "foreach()". And with development of this hobby project the interactions are getting more complex, so script execution time is getting crazy. Thats why i decided to store the whole bunch of data in RAM (considering that i can`t get the source in other format).
How can i store all that in RAM, without script consuming a crazy amount of RAM?
Example of code used:

```
  function SaXtA ($filenames, $ArrayName, $KeyAttrib)
    {   $list=explode(" ", $filenames);
    $Anames=array();
    global ${$ArrayName};
    ${$ArrayName}=array();

    foreach($list as $filename){
    if($filename!=""){
        $objector=simplexml_load_file($filename);



        foreach($objector->xpath('/idspace/Class') as $products)
        {


           $classId=0;
            foreach ($products->attributes() as $a => $b)
            {
/**
 * Don't really matter in which form i`ll have access to attributes.
 *
 */
                ${$ArrayName}[(string)$a][(int)$products['ClassID']] = $b;

            }


            }
        }}
    }

    $megaitems='';

    foreach (glob("./XML/datatable_item_*.xml") as $filename) {
        $megaitems.=$filename.' ';

    }
```

Comment: can you show the code sounds like a mem leak in one of your loops

Comment: People often use a "database" when they need fast access to a large amount of data. Would you be interested in using a pre-existing database engine instead of creating one from scratch?

Comment: Added code example.

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_file` loads the entire XML structure into memory. As the file gets larger, so does the memory usage.

Instead, you'll want to use PHP's [`xml_parse`](https://www.php.net/xml_parse), which will allow you to stream the file and process it as you step through it.